# Python: What is the most feature-rich library for loading audio metadata from various formats?

Tags: python, audio, metadata

I'm looking for a good, feature-rich, library for reading metadata from various audio formats (MP3, FLAC, OGG, WAV, etc.). I have already looked at Mutagen, but the documentation is nearly nonexistent, and it seems incapable of loading basic information such as artist and audio title.

Comment: what context / operating system?

Answer (score 1):

Are the artist and audio title encoded properly? What particular formats is it failing one - often ID3 information is poorly encoded.

http://wiki.python.org/moin/UsefulModules#ID3Handling (A List of ID3 modules)

I would try [ID3Reader](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/modules/id3reader.html), which has support for ID3v1, which Mutagen seems to be missing.

Answer (score 1):

see [taglib](http://developer.kde.org/~wheeler/taglib.html) and it's [python bindings](http://code.google.com/p/python-taglib/)

Answer (score 1):

another binding based on taglib (maybe the same as python-taglib?) called tagpy by Andreas -- http://mathema.tician.de/software/tagpy . I used it a while ago, and it's not bad... the following rough code should give you an idea how to copy tags from one file to the other (thus any other manipulation)

```
def copy_tags(src_file, dst_file): # args both strings
    tag0 = tagpy.FileRef(src_file).file().tag()
    file1 = tagpy.FileRef(dst_file)
    tag1 = file1.file().tag()
    for info in ['album', 'artist', 'comment', 'genre', 'title', 'track', 'year']:
        setattr(tag1, info, getattr(tag0, info))
    print file1.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

[gstreamer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gstreamer) is also an excellent option, if you don't mind the gnome dependency and a bit more effort coding. it supports just about every filetype known to man.