# How to get audio file metadata in python beyond regexes and id3 tags

Tags: python, audio, mp4, id3

Right now I'm working on a script that needs to extract the artist, album, and title from all these audio files.  At the moment, I first try to extract them with regular expressions, and if the files aren't named nicely I go the slow route and try to get the information with id3 tags.  The files then just get ignored if neither works.

Id3 tags only work with mp3 files though, so I was wondering if anyone knew any good id3 equivalent tag reading python libraries for some of the other popular audio file extensions.

Thanks!
Grant

Comment: Sorry just found a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985641/python-what-is-the-most-feature-rich-library-for-loading-audio-metadata-from-var 

Support for mp4 and m4a which I don't think any of those solutions address would really be ideal though :-)

Answer (score 3):

Use [mutagen](https://github.com/quodlibet/mutagen). It's a multi-format tag reading (and writing) library.

Comment: Upvoted this answer. The diveintopython tutorial only works for ID3v1 tags, not even the extended one